# Попытка вызвать WMI в DLL библиотеке приводит к зависанию

Tags: wmi, delphi-7

Я столкнулся с неприятной проблемой. Мне нужно получить уникальный HWID компьютера через WMI. Вот код:

```
  library gguard;

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils, 
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

{$R *.res}

function GetWMIstring(wmiHost, root, wmiClass, wmiProperty: string): string;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;//for access to a bind context
    Moniker: IMoniker;//Enables you to use a moniker object
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));//Converts a string into a moniker that identifies the object named by the string
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));//Binds to the specified object
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject(Format('winmgmts:\\%s\%s',[wmiHost,root]));
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM %s',[wmiClass]),'WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
     Result:=colItem.Properties_.Item(wmiProperty, 0); //you can improve this code  ;) , storing the results in an TString.
  end;
end;

var
    i,HWID: Integer;
    TString: String;
begin
 try
    HWID := 0;
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_BIOS','SerialNumber');
     for i:=1 to length(TString) do HWID := HWID xor (ord(TString[i]) shl (i-1)*2);
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_BaseBoard','Manufacturer');
     for i:=1 to length(TString) do HWID := HWID xor (ord(TString[i]) shl (i-1)*2);
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_BaseBoard','Product');
     for i:=1 to length(TString) do HWID := HWID xor (ord(TString[i]) shl (i-1)*2);
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_BaseBoard','SerialNumber');
     for i:=1 to length(TString) do HWID := HWID xor (ord(TString[i]) shl (i-1)*2);
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_Processor','Name');
     for i:=1 to length(TString) do HWID := HWID xor (ord(TString[i]) shl (i-1)*2);
     TString := GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_Processor','ProcessorId');
     HWID := HWID xor StrToInt(GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_Processor','UpgradeMethod'))
     xor StrToInt('$'+Copy(TString,9,8)) xor StrToInt('$'+Copy(TString,1,8));

    finally
    CoUninitialize;

    MessageBox(0,Pchar('Ну вот =)'+IntToHex(HWID,8)),'HWID Generator',MB_OK + MB_ICONSTOP + MB_DEFBUTTON1);

    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    Begin
        MessageBox(0,Pchar('Произошла ошибка :('+#13#10+E.Classname+': '+E.Message+#13#10+TString),'HWID Generator',MB_OK + MB_ICONSTOP + MB_DEFBUTTON1);
        TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess,1);
    End;
  end;
end.
```

Запускаю DLLку через EXEшник этим кодом:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var h: THandle;
begin
    h := LoadLibrary('gguard.dll');
    if bool(h) then
        FreeLibrary(h);
end;

end.
```

Но вот проблема. Если этот код выполнить под DLLкой, то напрочь зависает на строчке

```
OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
```

А именно зависает функция `MkParseDisplayName()`.
Но если пустить этот код прямо под EXEшник, то всё отлично, код работает. В чём может быть причина такого?

Answer (score 1):

Она у вас не просто зависает, а попадает в DeadLock. Почему это происходит написано [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). В двух словах:

Функция LoadLibrary работает так: Если указанный моудь (библиотека) еще не загружена для вызывающего приложения, система вызывает из библиотеки функцию `DllMain`. Это и есть ваш код между главными `begin` и `end` в библиотеке. В данном случае это конструкция `try..except`.

[На картинке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) видно, что перед выполнением `DllMain` система входит в критическую секцию (`LoaderLock`) и только после выполнения выходит из нее. Если во время выполнения `DllMain` системе понадобится загрузить другую библиотеку, это приведет к тому, что она попытается снова войти в эту же самую критическую секцию, только уже из другого потока. Таким образом ваш `DllMain` зависнет в бесконечном ожидании загрузки требуемой библиотеки. Что вы и наблюдаете.

[Чуть ниже картинки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#general_best_practices) написано, что **нельзя** делать в `DllMain`: создавать потоки, процессы, загружать библиотеки, выходить из потока и т.д. Там большой список.

Чтобы этого всего избежать, вам нужно свой код вынести из `DllMain` в экспортируемую функцию (см. справку по ключевому слову `exports`). И после загрузки библиотеки из приложения, получить адрес нужной функции (`GetProcAddress`) и пользоваться ей.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь работает, но проблема в том, что эту библиотеку я буду использовать в том EXEшнике, к которому у меня нет исходника. Т.е. я должен получить HWID во время инициализации DLL библиотеки.. Возможно ли хоть как-то это сделать? Т.е. к EXEшнику библиотеку я прикрепляю через PE Explorer.

Comment: Попробуйте перенести ваш код в секцию `initialization`.

Comment: Цитирую: "модуль DLL не имеет ни секции initialization, ни секции finalization." :(

Comment: Ну да, это я погорячился, насчет `initialization`. Ну, значит, не судьба...
А для чего вам нужно вызывать эту библиотеку именно в контексте определенной программы? Она же ничего в программу не возвращает. От контекста зависит `HWID`?

Comment: Скажу так. Это был написан тестовый EXEшник. Всё это будет у меня в клиенте онлайн игры. Исходника EXEшника с него у меня нету, по-этому приходится запихивать DLLку через LordPE, по-этому (как оказалось) я и не мог вызвать функцию получения HWID через DLLку нормально. Но я совсем забыл о том, что этот EXEшник нормально общается с ещё одной .des библиотекой, которую в свою очередь подгружает .dllка, которая была подключена через LordPE. И уже в тот DES я впихнул получение HWID. Как-то так :)
В итоге - заработало) Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Я все равно не понял, в чем соль. Зачем получать `HWID` из чужого приложения? Что мешает написать свою программу и получать в ней `HWID` сколько душе угодно?